# how to count the number of entries in the localstore

Tags: cordova

How to count the number of entries in the localstore.

I am setting the item through this

window.localStorage.setItem("email", email);

window.localStorage.setItem("password", password);

I want to know the how many entry of the email and the password in the local store.

please tell me about this.

Comment: To count the number of things stored on the localStorage use the code Washington Gueded promosed, but your question is a bit strange. How many entry of the email and the password? just 2, one for email and other for password, if you try to use it more than once it gets overwrited

Answer (score 1):

You can do a (for in) to see all setted items:

```
for (var xxx in localStorage) {
    console.log( xxx + "= " + localStorage[xxx] );
}
```

---

Or simply get the length:

```
console.log( localStorage.length );
```

---

Hope it helps :)